# If the origin is asymptotically stable for $z' = Az$...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

If the origin is asymptotically stable for $z' = Az$, prove that there exists $δ > 0$ (depending on A) such that if $||A − B|| < δ$ then the origin is asymptotically stable for $z' = Bz$.

My thoughts: Since $z' = Az$ is stable we know that the real parts of the eigenvalues of A are all less than 0. I know that I need a delta that makes sure that the real part of the eigenvalues of B are not greater than 0. I can't figure out how to write this though mathematically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial $P_A(\lambda) = \det(A - \lambda I)$ is a polynomial in the entries of the matrix $A$, and in particular is a continuous function of $\lambda$ and those entries.  Let $\Gamma$ be a closed positively oriented contour in the complex plane such that all eigenvalues of $A$ are  inside $\Gamma$.  If $\|B-A\|$ is small enough, $|P_B(z) - P_A(z)| < |P_A(z)|$ for all $z$ on $\Gamma$.
By [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem), $P_B$ and $P_A$ have the same number of roots inside $\Gamma$ (counted by multiplicity),
and thus all eigenvalues of $B$ are inside $\Gamma$.

Comment: Is the characteristic polynomial a way to define the  norm? I don't have a very good geometric understanding yet of that.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial doesn't define the norm, but its roots are the eigenvalues.  The norm defines the topology, in which the characteristic function is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

The origin is asymptotically stable for the system $\dot{x} = Ax$  **iff** there is some $T>0$ such that $\|e^{AT} \| < {1 \over 2}$.

Choose $\delta>0$ such that $\|e^{BT}\| < {1 \over 2}$ for all $B \in B(A,\delta)$.

Comment: thank you. Why is the number 1/2 that gives stability?

Comment: Any number less than one.

Comment: ah ok great thanks.

Comment: The point is that it is easier to see a connection between the perturbation of $A$ in terms of the state transition matrix than in terms of eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to show that the mapping "$A$ maps to the eigenvalue of largest real part of $A$" is continuous (as a function from $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ to $\mathbb{C}$) in your norm.

An intuitive way to see this result for "most" matrices is to use the implicit function theorem; this lets you define this eigenvalue implicitly through the characteristic equation. But this only works if the eigenvalue of second highest real part of $A$ has a strictly smaller real part than the highest one.

Elsewhere you need to be a bit more clever. One way is to change $B$ to the basis in which $A$ is diagonal and then apply Gerschgorin's theorem. But then *this* only works when $A$ is diagonalizable. So for instance neither of these approaches work for $A=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$. But there is yet another way out of that, which I will leave for you to figure out.

Comment: I have been thinking about this a lot tonight. I don't understand why the A is important to know and what the ||A-B|| has to do with the problem. Is it that we know how z acts on A so we want to use this to see what we need ||A-B|| to be so that z acts on B in a stable sense as well? Or does it have nothing to do with the z? If it has nothing to do with the z then I don't understand why we have to relate B to A. I guess my hang up is that any matrix with real(eigenvalues)<0 is going to be stable so why must we use A to state when the origin of z'=Bz will be stable?

Comment: It seems like B will either be stable or it won't regardless of what A is.

Comment: What B is even allowed to be in the first place depends on what A is, since the two must be close together.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will think on that some more. Do I want to use the jordan form or some other decomposition?

Comment: @Math4Life The Jordan form doesn't really help with this argument, because it isn't obvious that a small perturbation of a triangular matrix causes a small perturbation of the eigenvalues. But the diagonalizable matrices are dense, so given a non-diagonalizable $A$ you can make up a diagonalizable $C$ with $\| A - C \|<\delta_1$ and then select $B$ within $\delta_2$ of $C$ using the Gerschgorin argument. Then you just need to check that the eigenvalues of $C$ can be made close to those of $A$, then set $\delta=\delta_1+\delta_2$.